# How get spences by month on yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2

I need sum  all  expenses and income from each user on the same gridview and filter for each month. I have two sql querys  and works each one. but I need help for union o convert activedataprovider for yii2. If a did join the results thats wrong.

This is my code:

```
public function actionEstadistics()
{   
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;


    $sql = "SELECT date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m') AS periodo, 
    SUM(efectivo+valesotros) AS ingresos 
    FROM pagosing 
    WHERE user_id= $user_id    
    GROUP BY date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m')
     ";


   $sql2 = "SELECT date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m') AS periodo, 
    SUM(costototal) AS gastos 
    FROM garageservices 
    WHERE user_id= $user_id    
    GROUP BY date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m')
    ";


 $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => $sql,
    'pagination' => false
 ]);
```

Comment: why not do a loop and sum all expenses?

Comment: or do a join on pagsing and garageservices? and then do the sum?

Comment: let me post mi db  schema

Comment: @CabreraJess Is there any ralationship between pagosing and garageservices table ? So u can join and get records

Comment: yes , i can  get de sum  .   o relationship . only missing  groupby  month   , in relationship  and  gave me the error   Call to a member function groupBy() on string –

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have two model one is "User" and second one is "UserExpenses". Now you need to follow below steps :

1. Show grid of user detail model and take an action button inside action column
2. Link action button to another UserExpenses detail model grid there will detail of all expenses and income
3. You can use KartikGridView for show sum of expense and income column. It will also applied to filter data.
4. Apply month wise filter on UserExpense model grid details.

For more help please post your database structure. So I can post code for you. I  hope given scenario will work for you.

Comment: table user  - id,   table pagosing ,sum efectivo + vales ,user_id (income)  table garageservices  sum  costototal , user_id  , order for month   like   google charts   i try do join with  like                                                           $query = Pagosing::find()->select("date_format(created_at,'%Y-%m') AS periodo,  sum(efectivo) as ingresos)");
    $query->joinWith(['user']);  and   show this error    ------>Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'date_format'    and on separate query sql sum . its work

Comment: i want to make a chart monthly . i try on relation sum and groupby . like                                public function getPagosingMonth()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pagosing::className(), ['user_id' => 'id'])->sum('efectivo + valesotros')->groupBy('date_format(created_at,"%Y-%m") AS periodo,');
    }      and   get this error   -  Call to a member function groupBy() on string